# DRF- function missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: mongodb, django-rest-framework

I tried to insert data into mongodb without using models. When I run script I have got below error ,

**TypeError: get_db_handle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'**

this is my query.py

```
class Department(object):
    print(object)
    def import_department(self):
        data = ["IT", "FINANCE", "HR"]
        db_handle = self.get_db_handle(EVENT_STORE_DICT.get("DB_NAME"),
                                       EVENT_STORE_DICT.get("DB_HOST"),
                                       EVENT_STORE_DICT.get("DB_PORT"),
                                       EVENT_STORE_DICT.get("USERNAME"),
                                       EVENT_STORE_DICT.get("PASSWORD"))
        department_insert = self.insert_into_db(db_handle, data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
Department.import_department(DBMixin)
```

here, db handled method,

```
class DBMixin(object):
    def get_db_handle(self, db_name, host, port, username, password)
        client = MongoClient(host=host,
                             port=int(port),
                             username='',
                             password=''
                             )
        db_handle = client[db_name]
        return db_handle
```

How can i solve this problem. Please help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_db_handle` is a method of class `DBMixin` but you are calling it from class `Department` as self.get_db_handle().